# How to calculate this probability - Random selection of 18 items

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I am going over some GRE based questions and its been a while since I worked with probability. This is one of the questions

> 30% of Advisors have average client size b/w $500K and 1 million
>   dollars. 34% of Advisors have average client size b/w 1 million
>   dollars and 5 million Suppose a complete list of advisors is available
>   and 18 are randomly selected from the list.
>
> 1)What is the expected no. of advisors that have an average client
>   size b/w 500,000 and 1 million and and what is the expected no. of
>   advisors that have an average client size b/w 1 million and 5 million

I am getting confused by random selection. Arent we supposed to get a total count (total no of Advisors in this case) and then get a probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look up the definition of expected value.  A random selection is expected to have the same distribution as the whole, so $30\%$ of the selection is expected to be between $0.5$M and $1$M.  The expected value is a long term average, so it need not be an integer.

Comment: so 5.4 ? Is that correct for 30% ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: thanks. Marking as the answer